# Some charts stopped working in instance group monitoring after installing Ops Agent in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent

I have installed the new Ops Agent in a fleet of servers that are part of a managed instance group.

Since I did the update, some graphs stopped working in the "Monitoring" tab of the instance group.

Here's the screens
[image: instance group monitoring charst]

As you can see at 11:35am the CPU Utilization and disk IO graphs went to zero.

If I check each server "Observability" tab, all graphs are working and showing information:

Here's the CPU
[image: CPU Observability]

And here's the disk
[image: disk observability]

Is there something else I need to configure in the instance group to get the previous charts working? Is this a bug in the Google Cloud Interface?

Comment: Maybe you can share more details, what process did you follow to install the agent? Did you use Automatization tools or agent policies? or if you are sure that the Agent is running, but is not showing the data, please refer to this troubleshooting page: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/ops-agent/troubleshooting#not-sending-metrics

Comment: Also, you can find a complete checklist to help you address your issue more accurately: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/troubleshooting#checklist